# Grid View image click event goes to Image Slide view . Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

By clicking on any image in the grid view, all the images in the grid system should be reflected as a slide show. I do not know what the coding for this is. Let those who know to answer me

Comment: After click hide the gird then pass the gird list to slider and show it

Comment: hi Ramkumar, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you give us images of what exactly happens and examples of code or examples of what you've tried?